# Trying to make a Rock Paper Scissors game using Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a pygame rock paper scissors but I cannot figure out how to switch from player 1 to player 2. I want the player 1 text at the top to change to player 2 and the code to store what the first player picked. The problem is that I only am testing it for rock and it only changes when you are holding down left-click and have your mouse in the correct location instead of only having to click once.

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()
# Set up the drawing window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1000, 600])

# Run until the user asks to quit
running = True
while running:

    # Did the user click the window close button?
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    #Variables
    pygame.font.init()
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 50)
    rockColour = (0, 0, 0)
    rockLight = (100, 100, 100)
    paperColour = (255, 255, 255)
    paperColourBorder = (0,0,0)
    paperBorderLight = (100, 100, 100)
    scissorColour = (0, 0, 0)
    scissorLight = (100, 100, 100)
    P1Choice = ()
    Player1 = True
    Player2 = False
    white = (250, 250, 250)
    black = (0, 0, 0)
    #P1 Text
    textsurface = myfont.render('Player 1', False, black)
    screen.blit(textsurface,(400,25))
    # Fill the background with white
    screen.fill(white)
    #mouse
    mousepos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    mouseclick = click [0]
    mouserock = 125+150 > mousepos [0] > 125 and 225+150 > mousepos [1] > 225
    mousepaper = 400+150 > mousepos [0] > 400 and 225+150 > mousepos [1] > 225
    mousescissors = 850 > mousepos [0] > 700 and 375 > mousepos [1] > 255
    #ICONS UPDATES
    if Player1 == True and Player2 == False:
        if mouserock == True:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen,rockColour, (200, 300), (75))
            textsurface = myfont.render('ROCK', False, black)
            screen.blit(textsurface,(137,150))
        else:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen,rockLight, (200, 300), (75))


        if mousepaper == True:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,paperColourBorder, (400, 225, 150, 150))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,paperColour, (410, 235, 130, 130))
            textsurface = myfont.render('PAPER', False, black)
            screen.blit(textsurface,(400,150))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,paperBorderLight, (400, 225, 150, 150))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,paperColour, (410, 235, 130, 130))
        if mousescissors == True:
            pygame.draw.line(screen, scissorColour, (700,375), (850,225), 20)
            pygame.draw.line(screen, scissorColour, (850,375), (700,225), 20)
            textsurface = myfont.render('SCISSORS', False, black)
            screen.blit(textsurface,(635,150))
        else:
           pygame.draw.line(screen, scissorLight, (700,375), (850,225), 20)
           pygame.draw.line(screen, scissorLight, (850,375), (700,225), 20)

    #MouseClick
        if mouserock == True and mouseclick == 1:
            Player1 = False
            Player2 = True

        if 400+150 > mousepos [0] > 400 and 225+150 > mousepos [1] > 225 and click [0] == 1:
            P1Choice = ("paper")

        if 850 > mousepos [0] > 700 and 375 > mousepos [1] > 255 and click [0] == 1:
            P1Choice = ("scissor")
        #Player 1 text
        if Player1 == False and Player2 == True:
            textsurface = myfont.render('Player 1', False, (255, 255, 255))
            screen.blit(textsurface,(400,25))
            textsurface = myfont.render('Player 2', False, (0, 0, 0))
            screen.blit(textsurface,(400,25))    


    #Flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Done! Time to quit.
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so first all those variables need to be global as opposed to in the main game loop (so the variables should be above while running) otherwise when you increment them and than come back through the loop they will all be reset to what the originaling are implemented at and the loop keeps acting on them. Without a near fresh restart or severe edit I can’t simply show you all you need to do to make this work. I would suggest picking a tutorial that walks you through making a different game and learning the syntax and parts needed to make a game and than come back to your RPS game once you understand the parts needed to make your game function

Answer (score 0):

As @Pmac1687 points out, the code is re-setting all the status variables inside the main loop, so the state is lost at every loop iteration.

Furthermore the code is not getting single mouse events, but relying on the current state of the mouse.  This may loop through the "click-has-happened" code many times before the slow human releases the mouse button.  Changing this to be triggered on an event fixes this.

The screen paint order is a bit wrong too.  Some things are being written to the screen right before it's filled with white.

Anyway, I re-arranged the code a bit, and added the event handing for the mouse.  The screen-layout and clicks seem to do some stuff now.  Hopefully this will give you a little nudge in the right direction.

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()
# Set up the drawing window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1000, 600])

#Variables
pygame.font.init()
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 50)
rockColour = (0, 0, 0)
rockLight = (100, 100, 100)
paperColour = (255, 255, 255)
paperColourBorder = (0,0,0)
paperBorderLight = (100, 100, 100)
scissorColour = (0, 0, 0)
scissorLight = (100, 100, 100)
P1Choice = ()
Player1 = True
Player2 = False
white = (250, 250, 250)
black = (0, 0, 0)

# Run until the user asks to quit
running = True
while running:

    mouseclick    = False  # reset all these
    mouserock     = False
    mousepaper    = False
    mousescissors = False
    click         = [ False, False ]   # Mouse button clicks

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Did the user click the window close button?
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif ( event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN ):
            mouseclick = True
            mousepos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            click[ event.button-1 ] = True    # which button was pressed
            mouserock = 125+150 > mousepos [0] > 125 and 225+150 > mousepos [1] > 225
            mousepaper = 400+150 > mousepos [0] > 400 and 225+150 > mousepos [1] > 225
            mousescissors = 850 > mousepos [0] > 700 and 375 > mousepos [1] > 255

            if 400+150 > mousepos [0] > 400 and 225+150 > mousepos [1] > 225 and click [0] == 1:
                P1Choice = ("paper")
            if 850 > mousepos [0] > 700 and 375 > mousepos [1] > 255 and click [0] == 1:
                P1Choice = ("scissor")

    # Fill the background with white
    screen.fill(white)

    #P1 Text
    textsurface = myfont.render('Player 1', False, black)
    screen.blit(textsurface,(400,25))

    #mouse
    #ICONS UPDATES
    if Player1 == True and Player2 == False:
        if mouserock == True:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen,rockColour, (200, 300), (75))
            textsurface = myfont.render('ROCK', False, black)
            screen.blit(textsurface,(137,150))
        else:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen,rockLight, (200, 300), (75))

        if mousepaper == True:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,paperColourBorder, (400, 225, 150, 150))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,paperColour, (410, 235, 130, 130))
            textsurface = myfont.render('PAPER', False, black)
            screen.blit(textsurface,(400,150))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,paperBorderLight, (400, 225, 150, 150))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,paperColour, (410, 235, 130, 130))
        if mousescissors == True:
            pygame.draw.line(screen, scissorColour, (700,375), (850,225), 20)
            pygame.draw.line(screen, scissorColour, (850,375), (700,225), 20)
            textsurface = myfont.render('SCISSORS', False, black)
            screen.blit(textsurface,(635,150))
        else:
           pygame.draw.line(screen, scissorLight, (700,375), (850,225), 20)
           pygame.draw.line(screen, scissorLight, (850,375), (700,225), 20)

    #MouseClick
        if mouserock == True and mouseclick == 1:
            Player1 = False
            Player2 = True

        #Player 1 text
        if Player1 == False and Player2 == True:
            textsurface = myfont.render('Player 1', False, (255, 255, 255))
            screen.blit(textsurface,(400,25))
            textsurface = myfont.render('Player 2', False, (0, 0, 0))
            screen.blit(textsurface,(400,25))    


    #Flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Done! Time to quit.
pygame.quit()
```